# How to get body of vajra like Duryodhan?

Tags: yoga, meditation, duryodhana, yogi, gandhari

How to get body of vajra like Duryodhan?Is there a way, by tapas or yoga?I know yogis who can go on cold mountains without much clothing.

Comment: Why do want such siddhis?

Comment: for self defence and to uphold dharma @Rāmachandra

Comment: Get a mother like Gandhari who is able to impress Lord Shiva and who is an amsha of a Goddess.

Comment: @Sanatana Dhara nowhere in Mahabharat is it mentioned that due to Gandhari's power did Duryodhana get a body as hard as vajra.

Comment: Why Duryodhana who  caused injury to many ,in various ways inspired you ?  Bheema was truly superior  both in skill and character compared to Duryodhana in every way. Only on becoming Balaramas(Baldevs) disciple Duryodhana could progress .So  credit of all his skills revealing strength goes to Baldev only..Still if Duryodhana is your role model, you may  worship Balarama with devotion , and pray your wishes come true ...(@Rāmachandra ,  It's true that  Gandhari by her powers , would ve made him invincible. Its by mercy of Lord Krishna this was averted)

Comment: I was particularly asking about the siddhi because he wasnt born with it he got in his lifetime@Athrey

Comment: Its only by the power of austerities of his mother, she bestowed vajra deha, to Duryodhan(but with a weak point ) as in another comment...he did not attain it by his self effort or penance . Only by being a sincere disciple of Baldev , he had acquired certain appreciable skill.His overall capacity isnt  commendable in comparison with Bheema,  @AyushBora

Comment: So how can we attain this power by austerities?@Athrey

Comment: It can be attained thru yoga sadhana , and there should be a mention of it in Patanjali yoga sutras. Yama and Niyama, the stepping stones are hard to practice . Atleast the very first Yama, Ahimsa (not only by deeds, by words and thought), seems be great feat. I would say though it's not impossible, it is highly improbable(esp. in the age of Kali) By desiring such siddhis one may easily fall for a trap set by a commercial (imposter) yoga teachers of the modern world . @AyushBora